# Which is a better way to check request conditions?

Tags: python, django, request

Many times in open source codes of django python , I have seen the scenario like this

```
if request.META and 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META:
```

Similarly I have seen these two if conditions also

```
if request.POST and 'next' in request.POST:
if request.GET and 'next' in request.GET:
```

I believe that only one condition is suffice to check the if condition in these cases like

```
if 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META:
if 'next' in request.POST:
if 'next' in request.GET:
```

So why most of the time people use the earlier once, Is it just like double checking or there are some scenarios at which the first double check conditions may be useful while the later single check conditions might fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just grepped the whole (current git) source of django, and hadn't found a single occurrence of all three conditionals you mentioned.

And you are perfectly right with the one condition sufficing it *as long* as you can assume that all the three dictionaries are set. And looking at django code, I believe you can assume that.

*Edit*: also the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) suggests that those dictionaries will always be set.

Answer (score 6):

It can be acheived only by checking
 `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`
and 
`request.REQUEST.get('next')`
 instead of checking it for *`request.POST`* or *`request.GET`*

Comment: I don't remember if django has any magic for it but how would it handle `?next=` (i.e. empty value)?

Comment: In GET request type request.REQUEST.get('next') will return you '' if ?next= is there else it will give you None

Comment: And Python will give you `false` for empty value while the key check will give you `true`.

Answer (score 2):

There is one (hypothetical) case where your solution would fail:

```
>>> request.POST = None
>>> 'next' in request.POST
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

But if you can be sure that `request.POST` will never be `None`, then your solution would be OK.

It's just a little slower in the case of an empty dictionary because the `if 'foo' in request.POST` check can be skipped if the (fast) test for emptiness already fails. On the other hand, it will be faster if the dictionary is not empty.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {}", stmt="if a and 'next' in a: pass")
0.028279806566242852
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {}", stmt="if 'next' in a: pass")
0.04539217556517272
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {'foo':'bar'}", stmt="if a and 'next' in a: pass")
0.07471092295071458
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {'foo':'bar'}", stmt="if 'next' in a: pass")
0.045236056421884996
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {'next':'bar'}", stmt="if a and 'next' in a: pass")
0.0851067469988891
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="a = {'next':'bar'}", stmt="if 'next' in a: pass")
0.0520663758715898
```

So I guess this is a question of micro-optimisation. In that case, I invoke the Zen of Python: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I don;t think so request.POST can be None, unless somebody explicitly give it a value of None.

Comment: Michał Górny supports your view. @PiyusG says otherwise. I am not sure who's right :)

Comment: That he is talking about the parameter values as None, not the request.POST itself. It can be {} but not None I guess..after all POST and GET are only the instance of Query dictionary itself So they can't be None by themselves.